# ¿Como puedo detectar la posición del scroll de pantalla con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Mi duda sería la siguiente:
¿Puedo detectar en que posición esta el scroll de pantalla con javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te muestro un ejemplo con **Jquery** y otro con **javaScript** puro que hace lo que quieres:

**JQUERY**

```js
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log("Vertical "+scrollTop);
  console.log("Horizontal "+scrollLeft);
});
```

```css
.body{
width: 105%;
height: 700px;
background:#FFCC99;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
</div>
```

**JavaScript puro**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log("Vertical: " + window.scrollY);
  console.log("Horizontal: " + window.scrollX);

};
```

```css
.body {
  width: 105%;
  height: 700px;
  background: #FFCC99;
}
```

```html
<div id="body" class="body">
</div>
```

Comment: Justo me sirvió ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

**Podes usar:**

```
element.scrollTop // Vertical - Son los píxeles ocultos en la parte superior

element.scrollLeft // Horizontal - Son los píxeles ocultos en la parte izquierda
```

Para obtener el desplazamiento vertical y horizontal, respectivamente, que se ha desplazado.

**Aclaraciones:**

`element` puede ser `document.body` si necesitas saber de toda la página.
Podes compararlo con:

```
element.offsetHeight // Son la cant de píxeles (a lo alto) que ves en el navegador.

element.offsetWidth // Son la cant de píxeles (a lo ancho) que ves en el navegador.
```

si necesitas porcentajes. Osea, por ejemplo: El scroll esta en el 50% verticalmente.

Answer (score 4):

Sí, puedes usar `window.scrollY` y `window.scrollX` para comprobar en qué posición te encuentras.

Comment: Esto sería un comentario!

Comment: @Jorgesys creo que responde a la pregunta perfectamente, tal y como está planteada no hay mucho más que decir

Comment: No ha dicho cuando detectarlo (onscroll, onclick, ondrag....), sólo cómo saber el scroll realizado, así que no sabía qué más añadir

Comment: Entonces porque contestar una pregunta que no esta bien realizada, es mejor pedir aclaración al OP para brindar una respuesta correcta.

Comment: No está mal planteada, en mi opinión. Sencillamente la respuesta es corta: - ¿cómo se hace X? - se hace así.